# java-apns with http proxy problem

Tags: java, iphone, proxy, apple-push-notifications

my project used **java-apns** to send notification to iPhone. before that, i have to go through a http proxy. so i add proxy feature like this:

```
Proxyproxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost,
                Integer.parseInt(proxyPort)));
ApnsServiceBuilder apnBuilder = APNS.newService().withCert(certPath, passwd).withProxy(proxy);
```

but i always get invalid proxy error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Proxy
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:122)
at com.notnoop.apns.ApnsServiceBuilder.withProxy(ApnsServiceBuilder.java:281)
```

is there anybody could give me some advices? Thanks very much.

Comment: i joined java-apns mail group. it seems don't support http proxy so far.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is a bug in (Oracle) Java - only DIRECT and SOCKS proxy is supported for Socket. See https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6370908.